# JSP JSTL <a href call Onclick Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have the following code in JSP

```
       <a href="<c:url value="mycontroller">                            
       <c:param name="prod" value="${product.productNo}"/>                            
       </c:url>">Edit</a>
```

How can I call a Javascript onClick function to open a popup window and pass parameters?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPopUp() {
        window.open('mycontroller','width=650, height=450');
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<a href="javaScript:{openPopUp(\'parameter1\',\'parameter2\')}"></a>
```

Comment: PSR, `parameter1` and `parameter2`, can I pass `<c:param name="prod" value="${product.productNo}"/>`?

Comment: I have tried as `<a href="javaScript:{openPopUp('<c:param name="prod" value="${product.productNo}"/>')}">`, however it gives me compilation error `Error: Validator org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV reports:`

Comment: <a href="javaScript:{openPopUp('${product.productNo}')}"> and then set the parameter in the javascript function

Comment: I have set parameter in Javascript as `window.open('mycontroller?action=delete&pid&productNo'` and in a href `<a href="javaScript:{openEditWindow('${product.pid}','${product.productNo}')}">`. However both parameters are null in target.

Comment: @Polppan they are coming into javascript function or not

Comment: it comes as `mycontroller?action=delete&pid&productNo`

Comment: @Polppan what are the actual values

Comment: For `pid=C7800` and `productNo=PENGUINBOOKS`

Comment: BTW values varies as these are in a table, so each row has corresponding pid and productNo

Comment: @Polppan now you are getting values empty?

Comment: Yes in target values are null

Comment: My servlet class called mycontroller

Comment: please try to check by printing on the browser before sending to javascript function